# VBA anyway to execute _MouseDown before _Enter in TextBox?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

My intention is to open "birthdate" userform when textbox "bdayBox" is entered. And also want to be able to open "birthdate" userform again, if it was closed, by clicking with mouse inside the box, but only if textbox "bdayBox" is currently active.

My problem is, that if the textbox in not active and i click it with mouse, _Enter is executed before _MouseDown. This opens "birthdate" userform twice.
Is there a way to execute _MouseDown before _Enter or any other way to do, what i want without double openings?

*EDIT Before the user even gets to the put in birth date, they select how many people should be added. The form 'birthdate' should only show up, if there are more than 1 person to be added and it should appear automatically, when user is entering the 'bdayBox' textbox. If there is only 1 person, no extra form will appear and user enters birth date in the textbox itself. I want to take the decision from the user away to open the 'birthdate' form or not.

Current code

```
Public bdayBoxAct As Boolean

Public Sub bdayBox_Enter()   
    birthdate.Show
    bdayBoxAct = True
End Sub

Public Sub bdayBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    bdayBoxAct = False
End Sub

Private Sub bdayBox_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If bdayBoxAct = True Then
        birthdate.Show
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    bdayBoxAct = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this approach is not intuitive for the user, and suffers from the symptoms you are experiencing.  My suggestion is to place a button next to the `bdayBox` textbox, with an appropriate caption telling the user what the button will do, which they can press whenever they need to form to appear.  The button replaces the MouseDown logic.  Your code then becomes:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub bdayBox_Enter()
    birthdate.Show
End Sub

Private Sub ShowBirthdate_Click()
    birthdate.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, should have explained better, what i want. Before the user even gets to the put in birth date, they select how many people should be added. The form 'birthdate' should only show up, if there are more than 1 person to be added and it should appear automatically, when user is entering the 'bdayBox' textbox. If there is only 1 person, no extra form will appear and user enters birth date in the textbox itself. I want to take the decision from the user away to open the 'birthdate' form or not.

Comment: Whether the user clicks inside the box or presses a button, the user is still making a decision.  At least with this approach you don't get multiple forms.  The logic can always be enhanced as you describe.  Also, the form does appear automatically upon `Enter` plus whenever they press the button.

Comment: Ok i solved it with 'KeyUp' event with 'select case' for arrow keys. I removed the 'Enter' and 'Exit' events, since only arrows or mouse will be used. It is fine now and works how i want. Ty for your help, it put me on the right path.